# Does size of training data for an epoch matter in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Assuming we have 500k items worth of training data, does it matter if we train the model one item at a time or 'n' items at a time or all at once?

Considering `inputTrainingData` and `outputTrainingData` to be `[[]]` and `train_step` to be any generic tensorflow training step.

**Option 1** Train one item at a time -

```
for i in range(len(inputTrainingData)):
    train_step.run(feed_dict={x: [inputTrainingData[i]], y: [outputTrainingData[i]], keep_prob: .60}, session= sess)
```

**Option 2** Train on all at once -

```
train_step.run(feed_dict={x: inputTrainingData, y: outputTrainingData, keep_prob: .60}, session= sess)
```

Is there any difference between options 1 and 2 above as far as the quality of training is concerned?

Comment: It is usually used because it uses less memory and training can be faster as well due to frequent weight updates. Quality wise it shouldn't matter much, but very small batches can result in less accurate predictions.

Comment: You could train on batches of size 100.

Comment: @umutto Thanks.  `very small batches less accurate` - So, batch size of 1 can make significant changes in the training?

Comment: @CrisH Yes. I'm just trying to understand how the quality of training relates to the batch sizes.

Comment: @Achilles yes batch size of 1 could (would) make a significant difference in prediction results. Possibly you would see immensely erratic values in your cost function output.

Comment: @umutto Ok got it. I'm somehow getting better results with the batch size of 1 approach but its probably something to do with my test data, I guess. I'll look into it further.

Comment: @Achilles There are a lot more dependencies for getting better results, your may be overfitting, smaller batches help with that (erratic results mean more noise, and less overfitting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference. Option 1 is much less memory consuming but is also much less accurate. Option 2 could eat up all of your RAM but should prove more accurate. However, if you use all your training set at once, be sure to limit the number of steps to avoid over-fitting.
Ideally, use data in batches (typically between 16 and 256).
Most optimization techniques are 'stochastic', i.e. they rely on a statistical sample of examples to estimate a model update.
To sum up:
- More data => more accuracy (but more memory) => higher risk of over-fitting (so limit the amount of training steps)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm getting better results with the batch size of 1 approach but I guess its probably because of bad data or something.

Answer (score 1):

There is a different between this options. Normally you have to use a batchsize to train for example 128 iterations of data.
You also could use a batchsize of one, like the first of you examples.
The advantage of this method is you can output the training efficient of the neural network.

If you are learning all data at ones, you will bi a little bit faster, but you will know only at the end if you efficient is good.

Best way is to make a batchsize and learn by stack. So you can output you efficient after every stack and control your efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically these two methods are different. One is called stochastic gradient descent and the other is called batch gradient descent. You are missing the most commonly used one - mini batch gradient descent.  There has been a lot of research on this topic but basically different batch sizes have different convergence properties. Generally people use batch sizes that are greater than one but not the full dataset. This is usually necessary since most datasets cannot fit into memory all at once. Also if your model uses batch normalization then a batch size of one won't converge. This [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.08741.pdf) discusses the effects of batch size (among other things) on performance. The takeaway is that larger batch sizes do not generalize as well. (They actually argue it isn't the batch size itself the but the fact that you have fewer updates when the batch is larger. I would recommend batch sizes of 32 to start and experiment to see how batch size effects performance.

Here is a graph of the effects of batch size on training and validation performance from the paper I linked.

[image]